# Что быстрее: динамическое выделение памяти vs массив, Windows 7 vs Linux

Tags: windows, память, оптимизация, c++, linux

Написан тест для измерения скорости между динамическим выделением памяти и использованием массива, а также между  Windows 7 64 разрядная и Linux 64 разрядный под виртуальной машиной.

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int fff0 (int n)
{
  Point* p = new Point [n];
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
      p[i].x = i;
      p[i].y = i;
  }
  int i = p[n-1].y;
  delete [] p;
  return i;
}

int fff1 (int n)
{
  Point p[65536];
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
      p[i].x = i;
      p[i].y = i;
  }
  int i = p[n-1].y;
  return i;
}

void test()
{
  int nn[5][2]; // время вызовов отдельных функций
  int all;      // общее время выполнения

  int n = 100000;
  int m[5] = {10, 100, 1000, 10000, 65536};

  time_calc tc, tc_all;
  tc_all.begin();
  for ( int j = 0; j < 5; ++j )
  {
      tc.begin();
      for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
          fff0(m[j]);

      nn[j][0] = tc.get();

      tc.begin();
      for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
          fff1(m[j]);

      nn[j][1] = tc.get();
  }
  all = tc_all.get();
}
```

time_calc реализован с помощью:

```
Win                       Linux
QueryPerformanceCounter   ftime
```

Результаты:
 - время выполнения отдельных вызовов

```
        new ( fff0 )    p[65536] ( fff1 )
        win     linux   win     linux
10      5       5       10205   5
100     27      11      10156   14
1000    232     27      10440   48
10000   2295    204     13265   395
65536   15344   1301    30323   2547
```

- общее время выполнения:

  ```
  win     linux
  74392   3010
  ```

  Собственно 2 вопроса:
  1. Почему динамическое выделения быстрее использования массива, хотя используется *new* и *delete*?
- Почему *Linux* быстрее *Windows 7*?

PS. И там и там используется релизная версия с оптимизацией по скорости.

Comment: А хост машина под чьим управлением?

Comment: а потестируйте еще jemalloc и tcmalloc

Comment: Да что ж вы все смотрите на микрооптимизации? Оптимизируйте алгоритмы и не занимайтесь крохоборством.

Comment: хост машина под windows 7.
Это не микрооптимизация - это самая частая операция.

Comment: Микро, микро, не обманывайте себя. Когда ваш алгоритм будет бежать со скоростью (например) `O(log n)` вместо `O(n^2)`, у вас и мыслей об экономии на выделении памяти не будет.

Comment: @atropin, там у меня комментарии кончились.

*Почему Linux быстрее Windows 7?*

Если Вы уверены, что не ошиблись в измерении времени (и меряете в **миллисекундах**), то остается предположить, что компилятор при оптимизации выбрасывает часть кода.

Попробуйте немного его изменить:

    // в конце fff1() и fff0()
    ....
    i = rand() % n;
    return p[i].x + p[i].y;
    ....
    // в test()
    int s;
    ....
       s += fff0(m[j]);
    ....
       s += fff1(m[j]);
    ....
    printf("%d\n",s); // перед выходом из test()

Можете для контроля измерений времени запускать 

    time ./a.out

Comment: >Почему Linux быстрее Windows 7?

А мне кажется, тут еще могут быть неравные условия при компиляции, т.к.:

>Компилятор для Windows - VS 10

С этой точки зрения, тесты @avp более правдивы. И я бы советовал мерять время одним мерилом: `RDTSC` - в самый раз. И выполняйте процесс на одном ядре, чтобы избежать проблем с разными показаниями счетчика. Либо заведите комплексный счетчик (на все ядра) и используйте `RDTSCP`, но это очень неточный метод, т.к. контекст между замерами может прыгать между ядрами многократно, а показания будут сниматься с какого-то одного, это неправильно, но - вариант.

Comment: Кстати, как только будет возможным, думаю, стоит преобразовать вопрос в исследование.

Answer (score 11):

Тестируя скорость выделения памяти в варианте `p[65536];` вы на самом деле тестируете скорость цикла. Если посмотреть отладчиком, то это выделение - это просто изменения указателя стека (в разных реализациях может быть немножко по разному, но в целом - это просто изменения одного регистра). Это операция на несколько тактов процессора.

Разделив время на кол-во элементов для линукс версии видно, что оно прямопропорционально для случаев больше 1000 (что и не удивительно - меряем то цикл). Для маленьких циклов упираемся в точность измерения и накладные расходы. В windows варианте видимо просто накладные расходы немного больше.

В целом, все варианты тестируют скорость цикла, только win вариант с выделением на стеке выделяется. Нужно смотреть в код.

> Почему динамическое выделения быстрее использования массива, хотя используется new и delete?

а мы не выделение памяти тестируем, а скорость прохода по циклу. Но в случае с динамическим выделением возможно компилятор выбрал более удачных алгоритм прохода (скорее всего данные были выровнены по границе кратной 16 и все работало значительно быстрее).

> Почему Linux быстрее Windows 7?

у Вас тестирование различное. Одно тестируете на реальной машине, а другое на виртуальной. Тестируйте в одних условиях. Известно, что виртуальные машины иногда корректируют виртуальные системные таймеры, что может сильно искажать результаты тестирования.

**upd**

если компилировать fff1 с помощью gcc с параметром O3, передавая константу и не запрашивая результат, то компилятор вообще ее выбрасывает:) Компилятор далеко не такой простой.

Comment: В проекте используется передача данных по указателю в стороннюю библиотеку. Размер изначально не известен, кроме максимума. Цикл и возвращаемое значение имитирует работу этой библиотеки.

> Известно, что виртуальные машины иногда корректируют виртуальные 
> системные таймеры
 
Даже на глаз скорость различается в разы. В пользу linux. Буду смотреть выравнивание.

Comment: Я посмотрел в дизассемблере, хотя Ваши две функции очень похожи, компилятор (gcc), делает совершенно разный код.

Поэтому, если уж Вы решили делать такой синтетический тест, сделайте максимально одинаковые условие. То есть, код заполнения вынести в отдельную функцию.

> Даже на глаз скорость различается в разы. 

На таких мелких тестах погрешность может быть сильно разной. К тому же, посмотрев в код, который сделал gcc, я увидел там активное использование sse. То есть, может обрабатываться не по элементу, а по 4-8 за один проход. А это сильно ускоряет (особенно на выровненных данных).

Answer (score 6):

[@atropin](/users/11897/atropin), по моему Вы просто где-то с подсчетом времени *в Linux на порядок ошиблись*.

Кстати, какой у Вас CPU (вряд ли на порядок быстрее, чем у меня)?

Вы пишете, что вызываете ftime() и судя по всему приводимые Вами цифры это время в миллисекундах. Я прогнал Ваш тест у себя

```
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
```

и (по моим замерам) получил такие результаты:

**Windows 7 (gcc, g++  3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3))**

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ memtime.c 
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
Windows g++ (msec)
     N   stack    heap
    10      37     106
   100      51     119
  1000     310     374
 10000    2888    3002
 65536   28276   18728
Total: 53892 msec
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc -std=gnu99 memtime.c 
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
Windows gcc (msec)
     N   stack    heap
    10      24     102
   100      48     126
  1000     308     371
 10000    2902    2886
 65536   28030   18433
Total: 53230 msec
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ memtime.c -O3
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
Windows g++ (msec)
     N   stack    heap
    10      24       1
   100      32       8
  1000     105      83
 10000     843     819
 65536   14540    5264
Total: 21719 msec
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc -std=gnu99 memtime.c -O3
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
Windows gcc (msec)
     N   stack    heap
    10      21       1
   100      30       8
  1000     102      83
 10000     863     832
 65536   14522    5265
Total: 21727 msec
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

**Linux Виртуальная машина VirtualBox 4.2.10**

```
Linux avp-ubu1 3.2.0-39-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 28 00:28:53 UTC 2013 x86_64  GNU/Linux  (gcc g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3)

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc -std=gnu99 memtime.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Linux gcc (msec)
     N   stack    heap
    10      12      15
   100      66      87
  1000     358     306
 10000    3016    3125
 65536   20362   20595
Total: 47942 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ memtime.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Linux g++ (msec)
     N   stack    heap
    10      14      15
   100      71      90
  1000     353     329
 10000    3267    3191
 65536   20714   21119
Total: 49163 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ memtime.c -O3
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Linux g++ (msec)
     N   stack    heap
    10       7       3
   100      28      21
  1000     137      92
 10000     851     911
 65536    5599    5990
Total: 13639 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc -std=gnu99 memtime.c -O3
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Linux gcc (msec)
     N   stack    heap
    10       7       2
   100      34      16
  1000     125      62
 10000     878     646
 65536    5644    4845
Total: 12259 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Для того, чтобы оптимизатор не выбрасывал тестируемый код, я в нескольких местах добавил `volatile`. Время во всех случаях брал функцией `gettimeofday()` и пересчитывал в `long long` в миллисекунды с отбрасыванием их тысячных долей.

Результаты очевидно ближе к интуитивно ожидаемым.

Пожалуй несколько странным (точнее, для меня необъяснимым (а смотреть ассемблерный код просто лень)) выглядит результат в винде для N = 65536 (стек значительно медленнее кучи, тогда как в других тестах время примерно равно).

Comment: >стек значительно медленнее кучи, тогда как в других тестах время примерно равно

А если запереть стек в физической памяти(`VirtualLock`, не забывайте о прилилегии "Lock Pages in Memory" [после включения требуется ребут])?

Comment: У меня CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2500 CPU @ 3.40GHz.

Comment: @atropin, тогда результаты должны быть примерно такими же.

Я измеряю так:

    long long start_all = mtime(), start;
    ....
    start = mtime(); // tc.begin();
    ....
    nn[j][0] = mtime() - start; //tc.get();

а в mtime()

    ....
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
    return mt;

В винде MinGW, поэтому все собирается даже без условной компиляции.

А Вы в ней каким компилятором пользовались?

Comment: @mega, не понимаю

    А если запереть стек в физической памяти (VirtualLock)?

а куда стек может из физической памяти подеваться? Тут ее нужно-то полмегабайта.

Comment: >а куда стек может из физической памяти подеваться?

Он мог в нее просто не попасть :) Т.е. каждая из 16-17 страниц в таком случае, по-очереди, будет передаваться в физическую память **во время работы алгоритма**, что, может сказываться на Ваших замерах,  
 --  
кстати, убедитесь, что размер страницы в обеих системах одинаковый (обычно - 4Кб).

Comment: @mega, очевидно это не тот случай.

В обеих системах i7-2500 и i5-2500 эти страницы не то что в физической памяти, они в L3 кэше все время должны быть.

Вот, может в винде какие-то действия по ограничению L3 для процесса осуществляются? Правда я не знаю,  в возможно ли такое в принципе.

Comment: >В обеих системах i7-2500 и i5-2500 эти страницы не то что в физической памяти, они в L3 кэше все время должны быть.

Судя по анализу кучи процесса (я этим занимался пару лет назад), стек как раз в ней и размещается, по кэшам процессора он пойдет гулять только если будет "близковременное" обращение к каждой его виртуальной странице, которая предварительно должна быть хотя бы раз загружена в физическую память. Вы серьезно считаете, что старт любого процесса гарантирует такую загрузку в `Windows`? Я, конечно не утверждаю, но сомневаюсь, что при запуске винда подгружает неиспользуемый стек.

Comment: @mega, а это я ошибся в печати. На самом-то деле все обстоит с точностью "до наоборот". (Печатаю не тот заголовок).

Получается, что в винде с массивом в стеке (хотя в функции fff1() Point p[] размещается  не в стеке функции, а после стека main() !!! (попечатал адреса)) работает быстрее.

Видимо это можно объяснить особенностями кода, создаваемого gcc/g++ 3.4.5.

Но вопрос, почему **у автора такие цифры**, остался. Поэтому я его плюсану.

Comment: Коллеги! Прошу прощения. В тесте была ошибка. Результаты динамического выделения и использования массива одинаковые.

Поэтому остается второй вопрос:

Почему Linux быстрее Windows 7?

Компилятор для Windows - VS 10.

Comment: Я в своем вопросе уже отвечал. gcc сделал векторизацию с использованием sse. VS c++ - не смог. При правильной векторизации, вышеприведенный код можно ускорить до 4 раз (по сравнению с невекторизированным кодом). Но обычно ускорение 2-3 раза.